# Deploy website with git, only latest revision and track local changes

Tags: git, svn

I have a question regarding the recommended way of using GIT to deploy websites to live webservers but also be able to track changes on the webserver.

Background and old way how we are doing it with SVN:
We develop websites, deploy them **on customer servers** (which are not under our control) and hand the project over to the client and his own webmasters. Sometimes, years later we have to make changes to the websites.

To track (small) local changes to the website, for example when a webmaster fixes a typo, we check out a local SVN working copy to the webserver instead of just a SVN export.

By configuring the webserver we made sure that the hidden .svn directory is not accessible to webbrowsers.

By using this configuration we were able to track changes on the webserver, obviously. We are aware of the fact that some meta data and a copy of the website is deployed to the customers server (in the .svn Folder), but in the last 10 years, there was not a single problem with this setup ever.

Now we are moving our SVN repos to GIT and wonder how we can achive the same thing with GIT.
The only difference is, that we do **not want the whole GIT repo** and all commits on a customers webserver. Some projects are 15 years old and have thousands of commits and there is no reason why we should deploy the whole history to a customers server. We can happily live with the latest commit in a hidden .git directory, like it used to be with SVN, to track local changes.

Unfortunately, we were not able to find any solution to that problem, so I am asking here how we can do that.

PS: We want to get rid of SVN completely, so git-svn does not seem like a solution.

Thank you,
Berni

Answer (score 0):

Git allows to create shallow clones of repositories by using the `--depth` option. Use the following command to create a copy that contains only the last commit:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://example.com/myrepo.git
```

Just make sure that your git version is 1.9 or newer. Earlier versions had limited support for shallow clones.

From [git-clone Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> **--depth <depth>**
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. [...]